# Fill a text input from the scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a text input in a form that I want to fill with data I'm getting from a promise.

this is my text input :

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control input-lg"
ng-model="candidature.lastname"
required>
```

And In my controller I have this :

```
candidatureService.get({id: $rootScope.username}).$promise.then(function (res) {

      $scope.candidature = {};
      $scope.candidature.lastname = res.nom;

//code...

}).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Error getting data');
});
```

When I inspected my application using [batrang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) I can see that the object `candidature` in `$scope` has the value I'm getting using that promise :

[image]

And as you can see I have `ng-model="candidature.lastname"`.

Does anyone know why the text input doesn't get the value from the scope?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assign your response data to canditure first
like
$scope.candidature = res;
then you will get the value on form.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar if I did that I'll have something like this `$scope.candidature.nom` instead which will not work since I want to fill `$scope.candidature.lastname` and not `$scope.candidature.nom`

Comment: Declare this $scope.candidature = {}; before the service request then as it is making things blank thus you dont have output on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring `$scope.candidature = {};` before you make the API request...

But from the code it looks like you have only declared `$scope.candidature.lastname` and not `$scope.candidature.firstname`.

Comment: thanks that was the problem, I had to declare the object candidature outside the api request for `$scope.candidature.lastname` it was just an error in typing